# Retrieving preferences using Gdx.app.getPreferences

Tags: android, libgdx, preferences

I have a simple question (may be very dumb), however I did not find an answer goggling around.

I'm trying to save a simple preference say "high score" on my game that I'm using libgdx to build.

Here is my sample code -

```
Preferences prefs2;
prefs2= Gdx.app.getPreferences("MyPreferences");
prefs2.putString("name", "Donald Duck");
String name = prefs2.getString("name", "No name stored");   
font.draw(textBatcher, name, 55, 55);
```

Everything in the code (reading and writing to the xml file MyPreferences) works as expected except one thing; the high score stored on the file doesn't work when I restart the game. I definitely know that I'm missing something that is very simple but don't know what it is :)

Can any one please help me ?
I have also tried this -

```
Preferences prefs2;
if (prefs2 == null){
prefs2= Gdx.app.getPreferences("MyPreferences");
}
```

However it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're lacking a call to prefs2.flush() after you added the highscore item to the preferences object.
Straight from the libgdx docs:

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Preferences.html#flush()

Comment: Ugh.. Thanks! I had totally misunderstood the command prefs2.flush(); in fact I had assumed the exact opposite of what it does.